# redirect api data to a modal using angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a table being populated by a Get call. it is a list of jobs, i would like to be able to click on the job title so the user can view the job details in a modal. the setup i have put is what i have used when doing the same thing except the information is being sent to another view using the $location.it uses a GET (int id) call to pull the job information from the server. i have that part working for the views but when i try to do the same thing with the modal i get nothing. and for some reason i can not get the modal to open up on plunker? if anyone can help that would be great. i have done some reading on $routeparams but im not sure how to implement it. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/bbDEPKvkGRxpZRdqDB5a?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so there are a few things wrong. First your references at the top of script.js are incorrect. You are calling for route and not referencing it. Same goes for modal.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','$filter', function($scope, $filter, $route, $modal, $log) {
```

should be this

```
app.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','$filter','$modal', function($scope, $filter, $modal, $log) {
```

notice i took out route for now because i didnt have the url handy to put into the index file. you can put it back in but you must reference the file in the index page.

next you had

```
                    controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
```

in your getJobCartModal function. Not sure if you just copied and pasted something else from somewhere else but this should be

```
                    controller: 'MainCtrl',
```

next in the index file i think a couple of your paths were incorrect, some were missing the 'http:' prefix. Finally in the index page you have this

```
<td><a ng-click="getJobCartModal(singleJob.jobTitle)">{{job.jobTitle}}</a></td>
```

which should be this

```
<td><a ng-click="getJobCartModal(job.jobTitle)">{{job.jobTitle}}</a></td>
```

Comment: ok! i got it corrected. appreciate the help on that. any ideas on showing the data in the modal?

Comment: I've forked the Plunker, take a look. http://plnkr.co/edit/TaBjMYUFNFwFuiVL7P7C?p=preview

Comment: you have no idea how much i appreciate your help!